# Solving an integral equation with Laplace transform and convolution

Tags: analysis, laplace-transform, fourier-transform, convolution

So I solved the integral equation $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)f(x-t)\,dt = f(x)$ using the Fourier transform and convolution.

With $F$ as $f$'s Fourier transform, I found that $F²=F,$ then by using $F$'s continuity and integrability I concluded that $F$ was the null function on $\Bbb R$ and so was $f$. Now I've got a very similar equation to solve :

$$\int_{0}^x f(t)f(x-t)\,dt = f(x).$$

Now it still looks like a convolution product but from Laplace's transform point of view, which use is strongly recommended in order to solve this. I fail to see why the conclusion would be any different, though; can someone push me in the right direction? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe it helps to imagine you multiply with $B(t)$ box function 1 on $[0,x]$ and 0 outside and then change integration limits $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Then it would be a convolution. Such boxes are relatively straight forward to derive in Fourier and Laplace domains also.

Comment: @mathreadler That was my 1st approach, but in the context it is strongly advised to use Laplace's transform. $f$ is a function of $\mathcal L$$+(\Bbb R)$ so the integral as written in my original post is actually already a convolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}\bigg[\int_{0}^x f(t)f(x-t)\,dt &= f(x)\bigg]\\
F(s)\,F(s)&=F(s)\\
F(s)&=0\;\text{or}\;1\\
f(t)&=0\;\text{or}\;\delta(t).
\end{align*}
Here I'm using the Laplace Transform to go from the $x$ domain to the $s$ domain. You would need additional information to pick one of these answers.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Unfortunately this is all I've got, but I can choose the resolution framework so maybe that's the key to finding a unique solution, I'll look into that!